# LiveData does not call LifecycleRegistryOwner if standard Fragment is used

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying to use the standard Android fragments together with LiveData.
The update is triggered by updates in a Room Database.
Unfortunately my observer is not triggered.

Example code:

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements LifecycleRegistryOwner {

LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

@Override
public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
    return mLifecycleRegistry;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// ... normal code

    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getContext());
    LiveData<List<RssItem>> allRssItems = database.rssItemDao().getAllRssItems();
    allRssItems.observe(this, rssItems -> setListContent(rssItems));
```

}

If I enforce to ignore the lifecycle events, I receive the updates.

```
 allRssItems.observeForever(new Observer<List<RssItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<RssItem> rssItems) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setListContent(rssItems);
        }
    });
```

Can someone spot my error? I'm not using the v4.Fragment but the standard Android one but as I copied the implementation from LifecycleFragment into my code, I assume that this should work.

Comment: Probably a variation on [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62160522).

Comment: Thanks, Mark, that is indeed the issue. Using the workaround described in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62160522#comment1 solves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from CommonsWare and the link to the bug solve this question. For standard fragment you need trigger yourself the corresponding lifecycle events, e.g., lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE);